# Connecting to ADLS Gen 2 using Service Principals

Tags: python, azure-data-lake, service-principal

Can anyone show any python code I can use to connect to ADLS Gen 2 using Service principals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, install the following libraries:

[azure-storage-file-datalake](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-datalake/)

[azure-identity](https://pypi.org/project/azure-identity/)

Then use the code below:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential

tenant_id="xxx"
client_id="xxx"
client_secret="xxx"

credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id,client_id,client_secret)
service = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/",credential=credential)

#create a file system in ADLS Gen2
file_system_client = service.create_file_system(file_system="myfileSystem")
```

More code examples are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python).